# What does the column BYTES and USER_BYTES of table dba_data_files mean

Tags: oracle10g

So, I ran the query

```
select * from dba_data_files
```

I want to know what does the column `BYTES` and `USER_BYTES` mean. Does BYTES mean the space allocated and USER_BYTES mean the space that is used up? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3083.htm):

`BYTES` Size of the file in bytes

`USER_BYTES` The size of the file available for user data. The actual size of the file minus the USER_BYTES value is used to store file related metadata.

On my system, for example, `BYTES-USER_BYTES` is exactly 1,048,576 (1M) for each file.

In this context, "space allocated" and "space used up" are effectively the same thing - i.e. space allocated on disk = space used on disk.

To find out how much free space is available (e.g. for new tables & indexes or growth of existing ones), query `dba_free_space`.